# Location of Git Path on Windows

Tags: bash, git-bash, pm2, cmder

Overall, I am attempting to execute:

pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production

I am on a Windows machine and I have tried many different shells (CMD, Babun, Cmder).

On Babun, the error is:

[image: Babun error]

So, something about Git is not accessible. However, I know Git is accessible and defined in my Environment Variables on Windows b/c I can run "git --version" without issue.

Luckily, I was able to glean a bit more info about the problem through testing this out on Cmder:

[image: Cmder error]

Voila (or so it seems)! It appears that some path variable (likely to Git) just needs to be escaped by quotes (") b/c stupid Windows has "Program Files" as two words by default. Great!

Now, how do I find the file that holds that path?

- 6 hours later... *

Where the hell is that file?!?!?!!

- 3 hours later... *

Stack community, help me?!?!?!

Comment: Sounds like `git` is not installed on the remote server. This has nothing to do with your local windows box. You can see that `git` commands are working fine locally. It's only after attempting to deploy to your remote server and that deployment attempts to do something like `git pull` on that remote server that it breaks down.

Comment: The git pull is on the remote server? I just assumed that pm2 would pull any changes down locally and copy from local to remote but it sounds like you're saying that the remote server does the pull direct from github?

Comment: Also, I am certain that Git is installed on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your bash script which does the deployment (the `hook pre-deploy`, define in a [`ecosystem.json` file](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/#complete-tutorial)).

But it should include at line 6 a cd ${someVariable}, which should actually be `cd "${someVariable}"`, to take into account path with space in it.

Comment: I don't define a pre-deploy for pm2. pm2 must be doing it's own default stuff. Do you know where I could find that file?

Comment: @Nick It should be in the current folder where pm2 is executed.

Comment: That folder is completely empty

Comment: In other words, the directory I'm at in CMD when executing pm2 is empty. I don't know where pm2 got installed on the machine.

Comment: @Nick Then do a search for that file.

Comment: Just search "pm2"?

Comment: @Nick or search for `ecosystem.json`: pm2 operations depend on that file.

Comment: @Nick Yes, that is the idea (depending on the OS/shell used on the remote side)